How can I parse JSON to a heterogeonus nested struct in Ruby?
Let's say I have
A = Struct.new(:name, :languages, :index)
where :sections is supposed to be an array of items of this class:
B = Struct.new(:language, :text)
So, a JSON like this:
{
  "name": "Greetings",
  "languages": [
    {
      "title": "English",
      "text": "Good day"
    },
    {
      "title": "French",
      "text": "Bonjour"
    }
  ],
  "index": {
    "Good": "English",
    "day": "English",
    "Bonjour": "French"
  }
}

should parse as expected.
I also want to get informed if there is an invalid key, e.g. if there is a "text": entry near "name":.
A raised exception would be preferred, but anything else that the caller can observe is fine, too.
I know I can do JSON.parse(str, {object_class: A}), but this will try to parse the "sections" part as an A and fail.
Also, it won't use Hash for "index":, and fail even more miserably.
Plus, there won't be an A object or B subobject with their declared class functions.
I probably could use JSON.parse(str, {object_class: Struct} or OpenStruct, but that will happily accept any erroneous keys in the JSON hashes. And it's definitely necessary to check for invalid keys at that point, whether during parse or in a separate step.
What should I do?
Full disclosure: I'm just learning Ruby, so I won't be surprised if there's some simple way to achieve parsing and checking for key validity (value validity might also become an issue but isn't right now).

Parsing and validating the data are two completely different concerns. I'm not a fan of parsing your data directly into a Stuct or OpenStruct as it provides no advantages over a hash and you should probally have actual domain objects that encapsulate the data in your applications (for example the Model in MVC). OpenStruct adds significant overhead and is soft depreachiated. There are tons of different approaches for validating input. For example  JSON schemas, DSL's and encapsulating the validations in your domain objects like Rails does.

Also if your writing an web application on Rack the parsing of user input is done way down at the bottom of the stack and is a framework level concern while validating the data is a domain specific concern. The only time you would actually manually parse JSON  (if your doing it right) is when reading it from a file or when doing server to server communication.

@max The JSON is hand-edited, so syntax and key errors have the same source and need to be fixed by the same person (this is a domain requirement). Normally I'd separate the two myself, but not in this case.

@max It's an offline tool that reads a few files, transforms them, and emits them to an output directory. No webservices, no Rack, no Rails.

I do have a requirement that makes Hashes inferior: The configuration objects are real objects with behaviour, such as error message formatting, transformation code, etc. I can separate the two, but that separates configuration and the code that operates on it, so I can get issues with the two going out of sync. I'd like to keep them together, as one should do in OO.

You want a JSON Linter for that use case which you test the JSON with before sending it through a parser. A linter gives much more helpful feedback and will catch stuff that a parser will happily parse like duplicate keys.

I'm not saying that you should not use objects - I'm just saying it's not the parsers job to convert the input into those objects. OO doesn't mean jam everything into the least amount of components. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual-articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

You may want to have a look at the dry-* collection of libraries. As they provide substantially all of the mechanism's and processes you are looking for.

You can use pattern matching if you want, but as others have said you need to parse first, then extract the data or keys you want no matter what else you're doing. Nested JSON is an absolutely terrible storage format, so consider YAML , YAML::Store, or an actual database instead.

No answers, just frame challenges, so here's what I ended doing:
Parse first, then feed the hash into the constructor to do the validation.
Something like this:

# Read a data field from the JSON and 
def yank_json_field(json, field)
  result = json[field]
  json.delete(field)
  result
end

class JsonPopulatedClass
  # json_data is from something like JSON.parse(File.read(filepath))
  # Making the constructor accept a hash so it's testable.
  # This code assumes the data is from JSON, but actually it could be from
  # anywhere. However, it's destructive on the input hashes, so they should
  # be temporary, and I fail to imagine what use cases other than JSON would
  # give a temporary hash.
  def initialize(json_data)
    # For each expected field: (1) get the data, (2) do any validation.
    self.titles = yank_json_field(json_data, 'titles')
    # Do any default values needed.
    self.titles = {} if self.titles.nil?
    # This one needs to be a hash.
    raise "titles must be a hash but was #{self.titles.class}" unless self.titles.is_a?(Hash)

    # Untested: subobject
    self.subobject = Subobject.new(yank_json_field(json_data, 'subobject'))
    # Should be the same kind of constructor that raises with invalid data.

    # Here's a primitive field.
    self.website_root = yank_json_field(json_data, 'website_root')
    # Default value; it's a truthy value and nil would be fine, but whatever.
    self.website_root = false if self.website_root.nil?

    # Unknown data probably means there's a typo in a field name,
    # so it should be reported.
    raise("Extraneous JSON data #{json_data}") unless json_data.empty?
  end
end

Is is "far too hand-coded" for my taste, but there's the advantage that one can do all kinds of field mappings and outlandish validations as needed.
Which is also a disadvantage, because any maintainer has to look through all the constructors of objects and subobjects to catch any specialties that might be happening.
Distractions:
YAML? Sure, it would allow annotations about types. However, the input data is hand-edited, and type information shouldn't be in the input data.
Separate validation and parsing? That's a somewhat blurry subject, do you consider invalid field names a syntax or a content error?
The above recipe lets JSON.parse catch errors with JSON structure but checks field names; essentially, it's just a question of what kind of exception or error handling to do for each class of error, which is the application's domain (mine happens to be hand-edited JSON, where the difference is entirely irrelevant because whatever the error is, the editor needs to open the JSON file and correct the mistake).
